# How to send any InputStream to JMS Queue?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, jboss7.x

It is not sending it because InputStream is not Serializable. Is there any option to do this?
Different InputStreams will contain different sources to read from so it's better if I can send InputStream directly to JMS queue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send a stream, you have to "materialize" it before:

1. Read the stream into a byte array
2. Use a [BytesMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html): See [writeBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html#writeBytes%28byte%5B%5D%29)

As an alternative have a look at this [BytesMessageOutputStream](http://massapi.com/source/resin-4.0.20/modules/resin/src/com/caucho/jms/util/BytesMessageOutputStream.java.html): This way you should be able to stream, however the `BytesMessage` probably needs to buffer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

An inputstream generally points to some resource.  This resource might not be available to the consumer of your queue.

You can convert your inputstream to a `byte[]` which represents the loaded resource and send it that way.